# Use current-grouping-key assigned to variable in a predicate

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm having trouble, converting an existing xslt1.0 stylesheet to 2.0.

**I'm using Saxon as processor.**

Problem is at this instruction :

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$currentArt/MAPs/typeMAP[ERs/er/code= $ERval]" group-by="refCde">
```

where the variable "ERval" is set using the current-grouping-key function in another for-each-group.

ERval gets set to a xs:untypedAtomic, and I have the error "**Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(), supplied value has item type xs:untypeAtomic.**"

I tried different things, but i'm missing something.

Can someone expalin, how to achieve that, and point me the documentation section explaining it ?

Thank you for your help.

XML input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<art>
    <MAPs>
        <typeMAP>
            <libArt>ANJOU TOLERIE</libArt>
            <ERs>
                <er>
                    <code>18</code>
                </er>
                <er>
                    <code>21</code>
                </er>
            </ERs>
            <refCde>1234</refCde>
        </typeMAP>
        <typeMAP>
            <libArt>ARTICLE HOTELIER</libArt>
        </typeMAP>
        <typeMAP>
        <libArt>BOOK</libArt>
            <ERs>
                <er>
                    <code>18</code>
                </er>
            </ERs>
            <refCde>5678</refCde>
        </typeMAP>
        <typeMAP>
            <libArt>ARTICLE HOTELIER</libArt>
        </typeMAP>
    </MAPs>
</art>
```

Stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
        
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//art"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="art">
        <xsl:if test="./MAPs/typeMAP/ERs/er/code">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="./MAPs/typeMAP" group-by="ERs/er/code">
                <!--            call template passing ERval-->
                <xsl:call-template name="template">
                    <xsl:with-param name="currentArt" select="."/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="ERval" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="template">
        <xsl:param name="currentArt" select="''"/>
        <xsl:param name="ERval" select="()"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$currentArt/MAPs/typeMAP[ERs/er/code = $ERval]" group-by="refCde">
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>

    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please reduce your examples to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve]

Comment: Also tell us which XSLT processor you use.

Comment: Your problem cannot be reproduced using the code you have posted: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aB9NJX

Comment: And it always helps being as specific about details like the XSLT processor as possible, so tell us exactly which version and edition of Saxon you use if you expect someone to reproduce the problem you say you encounter.

Comment: Problem might have lied in a typo somewhere, because I got it working, including another use case described in the fiddle I posted below. Guess i failed to translate it to a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks Martin and michael. Indeed, i'm not very used to asking question here, as I normally find answer to problems somebody already asked for. I will provide everything in the future. Thanks for your reactivity in helping others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="refCde">` instead of `<xsl:for-each-group select="$currentArt/MAPs/typeMAP[ERs/er/code = $ERval]" group-by="refCde">`.

Comment: you are correct, in the example I provided, that was the goal. But in the whole stylesheet, in some case, I might have something more like this :https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93F8dU4

This example works now, and after a bit of investigation, it may have been a typo somewhere, that made it fail...I have no idea where it was.
Many Thanks for your help.